# Can String.Split differentiate between a single instance and multiple instances of a char?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, markdown

I am using C# String.Split.

I want to split on '#', but not '##', '###', '####' etc. I only want to split on single instances of the character, not multiple instances.

I am doing some work with markdown files. This is an sample piece of markdown I am using. I want to split sections 1, 2 and 3 but not the sub sections. By default it is splitting all instances of '#' so I am getting 14 strings in my array.

```
#Section 1
This is a sample section, it has two sub-sections

##SubSection 1.1
This is sub-section 1.1

##SubSection 1.2
This is sub-section 1.2

#Section 2
This is a sample section, it has three sub-sections

##SubSection 2.1
This is sub-section 2.1

##SubSection 2.2
This is sub-section 2.2

##SubSection 2.3
This is sub-section 2.3

#Section 3
This is a section without any sub sections
```

Comment: No, use Regex.Split instead after defining the correct pattern

Comment: `string.Split` looks at the string on a per-character basis, so it does not look “around” to see if the same character appears multiple times. It sees every character separately.

Comment: Do you mean that if there are multiple `##` that you want to leave that part of the string together? So that `ab#cd##ef` would split as `{ "ab", "cd##ef" }`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split`:

```
 var parts = Regex.Split(source, @"(?=^#[^#])", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

where:

- `(?=` ... `)` matches anything inside the parenthesis as lookahead (including it with the result, rather than discarding it as delimiter)
- `^` with `RegexOptions.Multiline` represents a start-of-line anchor
- `#[^#]` matches a hash followed by a non-hash character

In line with `Split` semantics, the first string in the returned array will be the substring occurring *before* the first section header. For your example, this would be an empty string, which you presumably want to discard.

Comment: Won't this split on the last `#` of every `##`?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. I just tried it with `Regex.Split("a#b##ef", @"(?=^#[^#])", RegexOptions.Multiline)` and got the original string back.

Comment: @Rawling: No. The `^` requires your hash to be preceded by a start-of-line.

Comment: @Enigmativity: The example given by the OP shows that each section starts on a fresh line.

Comment: @Douglas Ah, gotcha. Sneaky.

Comment: Nice.  I was looking for a solution that returned the results in a match collection.  This is better.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, that does what I wanted to do. Thanks to everyone else for the discussion and clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve this using `string.Split` just use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
var value = "### Text";
value.Split (new[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // returns new [] { " Text" }
```